# Can't highlight in terminal with mouse

Tags: command-line, mouse, gnome-terminal

I'm on a fresh install of 15.10 and for some reason, I can't highlight text in the terminal to copy. It's really weird and I've never run into this before.

The only thing a little different about my setup is that I also have Mint installed on a separate partition and share the home folder. However, I did follow some other answers I found that were very loosely related and deleted the `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal` directory but that didn't do anything.

I know it sounds like a minor bug but it definitely saves time being able to highlight and copy issue tracking numbers to paste into commits.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! (but please don't berate me for sharing my home directory between distros because that's not helpful)

Comment: Sharing the /home partition might actually be the problem here. What terminal-emulator does Mint use by default? Have you tried re-installing gnome-terminal? (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal`)

Comment: I tried re-installing it and it didn't work for my user, but I created a new user and it worked for that user. Which leads me to believe that it is because it's being shared. Now I'm wondering if there is another config file I'm missing that I can update. I don't really plan to use Mint much more.

A little background about my setup: my company installed Mint before I started. I felt it was meh and liked Ubuntu a lot better. The company said it was OK to dual boot it and I should be able to share the user profile between the two.

Comment: If you don't mind switching to another terminal emulator, I'd suggest `sakura`. Close enough to gnome-terminal in looks and customizability. Try it out

Comment: Can you highlight text if you press and hold Shift?

Comment: @Serg thanks for the suggestion, but that had the same problem.

Comment: @egmont Holding shift didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @WillSteinmetz I can only advice to run `script` command, which allows saving output of your terminal session to a file, but other than that - it's a bug, most likely in GUI rather than in terminal in particular.

Comment: Does highlighting work in other Gtk+ apps, such as gedit?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I mean, it might actually be selecting but not showing anything. Try selecting something (click and drag, as normal) and then middle-clicking. Was your selection pasted?

Comment: @terdon yes, I'm sure. That was the first thing I thought to try but had no luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly sounds like an issue caused by sharing your `$HOME`. I can't really tell you which file is the problem since I can't reproduce, but here are some tips.

You can use `strace` to trace what a program does when it is run. For example, on my system, it shows me that it accesses the following files from my home directory:

```
$ strace gnome-terminal 2>&1| grep -oP '/home/terdon/.*(?=")'
/home/terdon/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/home/terdon/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/home/terdon/.local/share/themes/Default/gtk-3.18/gtk-keys.css
/home/terdon/.local/share/themes/Default/gtk-3.16/gtk-keys.css
/home/terdon/.local/share/themes/Default/gtk-3.14/gtk-keys.css
/home/terdon/.local/share/themes/Default/gtk-3.0/gtk-keys.css
/home/terdon/.themes/Default/gtk-3.18/gtk-keys.css
/home/terdon/.themes/Default/gtk-3.16/gtk-keys.css
/home/terdon/.themes/Default/gtk-3.14/gtk-keys.css
/home/terdon/.themes/Default/gtk-3.0/gtk-keys.css
```

I don't really see which one of these could be causing the issue though. However, I'm not running Ubuntu so your output might be more useful.